# To draw a dot for an element, named as $x$ in set $X$

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a diagram of mapping like that:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
      elps/.style 2 args={draw,ellipse,minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2},
      node distance=3 cm,
      font=\footnotesize,
      >=latex, }
   \node(y)[elps={2cm}{3cm},label={below left:$X$}]{};
    \node(v)[elps={2cm}{3cm},right=3 of y,label={below left:$ Y $}]{};
    \node(z)[elps={2cm}{3cm},right=3 of v,label={below right:$Z$}]{};

    \draw[->](y)to[bend left=10] node[below]{$ f $}(v);
    \draw[->](v)to[bend left=10] node[below right]{$ g $}(z);
    \draw[->](y)to[bend right=40]node[below]{$ h $}(z);
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I want to point out  one element $x$ from $X$ and then $f(x)$ in $Y$ . So how can I draw a dot, named as $x$ in $X$. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable and add a little graphic of what you want to have as I do not understand the text. Maybe, I just don't get it because it is not my field of mathematical knowledge but in any case, you will find more helpers, if you become clearer of what you have, what you have tried, where you have failed, and what you are looking for now.

Comment: Well, now seeing Stefan's answer, I think it was yet understandable...

Answer (score 3):

For example, with an additional bullet style:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
      elps/.style 2 args={draw, ellipse,minimum width=#1, minimum height=#2},
      node distance=3 cm,
      font=\footnotesize,
      >=latex,
% Add this style:
     bullet/.style = {circle, inner sep=1pt, fill}}
    \node(y)[elps={2cm}{3cm}, label={below left:$X$}]{};
    \node(v)[elps={2cm}{3cm}, right=3 of y,label={below left:$ Y $}]{};
    \node(z)[elps={2cm}{3cm}, right=3 of v,label={below right:$Z$}]{};

    \draw[->](y)to[bend left=10] node[below]{$ f $}(v);
    \draw[->](v)to[bend left=10] node[below right]{$ g $}(z);
    \draw[->](y)to[bend right=40]node[below]{$ h $}(z);
% Add:
    \node (element) [circle, inner sep = 1pt, fill,
      below left = -0.5cm and -1 cm of y, label = {below right:$x$}] {};
    \node (element) [bullet, below left = -0.5cm and -1 cm of y,
      label = {below right:$x$}] {};
    \node (value) [bullet, above left = -0.5cm and -1 cm of v,
      label = {below right:$f(x)$}] {};
    \draw[->, dashed] (element)  to[bend right=20] (value);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying for. Thanks a lot.